# Counting daily and hourly results in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, datetime, wordpress

I have two tables in mySQL, one for views and one for downloads with the following key structure:

```
ip          | hit
---------------------------------------
127.0.0.1   | 2015-02-08 15:16:59
127.0.0.1   | 2015-02-08 15:20:22   
127.0.0.1   | 2015-02-08 15:20:35   
127.0.0.1   | 2015-02-08 15:21:13
10.0.1.1    | 2015-02-09 16:29:13
10.0.1.1    | 2015-02-09 16:42:12
10.0.1.1    | 2015-02-09 16:52:30
10.0.1.1    | 2015-02-10 10:52:30
10.0.1.1    | 2015-02-10 10:52:30
10.0.1.1    | 2015-02-10 12:52:30
```

I need to return a query that will count how many rows there are every day, ideally it would also return empty days/hours but I can fill those gaps in with PHP easily if the SQL query would be overly complex.

```
time        | count
---------------------------------------
2015-02-08  | 4
2015-02-09  | 3
2015-02-10  | 3
```

I also need to get the same information on a hourly basis

```
time                          | count
---------------------------------------
2015-02-08 15:00:00           | 4
2015-02-09 16:00:00           | 3
2015-02-10 10:00:00           | 2
2015-02-10 10:00:00           | 1
```

So far i have the following query after cobbling together a few I found online into something that actually works, but it only returns the day of the month as being unique and I need to have the query be stretchable over multiple months so only knowing the day is not massively helpful.

```
select dayofmonth(hit) as Day_of_month, count(*) as records from table_name hit >= '2015-02-01 00:00:00' and hit <  '2015-03-01 00:00:00' group by dayofmonth(hit)
```

I've seen a fair few of these similar posts around but the only ones I have found use functions not present in mySQL it seems, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**

After much more fiddling I now have it returning counts for each date with the following which i can easily enough limit by wheres, however I'm still none the wiser to getting this to work on an hourly basis.

```
SELECT date(hit) AS The_Date, count( * ) AS count FROM table_name GROUP BY The_Date ORDER BY The_Date ASC
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to do that could be using *[date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)* function

- To get all records grouped by day

  ```
  select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d') time, count(*) from test group by time order by time;
  ```
- To get all records grouped by hour

  ```
  select date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') time, count(*) from test group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') order by time;
  ```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef18c4/3) is sqlfiddle for your example

Comment: I wanted to post similar answer, but you've been faster :) +1

Comment: I made my edit a couple of min before you posted this, do you know whats faster date_format(hit, '%Y-%m-%d') or the date(hit) that what I have?

Comment: I also made a change where i set group by date_format(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H') to time, don't suppose you know if that would be faster? I assume it would due to not having to re run a function.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DATE(hit) AS Day, HOUR(TIME(hit)) AS Hour, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM table_name
GROUP BY Day, Hour
```

(edited)